# Dplyr and multiple t test (keeping the same IV)

Tags: r, plyr, inference

I'm using this [pretty nice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26244321/dplyr-summarise-multiple-columns-using-t-test/26247766) code to perform a multiple t.test keeping the independent variable constant!

```
data(mtcars)
library(dplyr)
vars_to_test <- c("disp","hp","drat","wt","qsec")
iv <- "vs"
mtcars %>%
  summarise_each_(
    funs_( 
      sprintf("stats::t.test(.[%s == 0], .[%s == 1])$p.value",iv,iv)
    ), 
    vars = vars_to_test)
```

Unfortunately, dplyr was updated and I've been facing this report

> `summarise_each()` is deprecated. Use `summarise_all()`,
>   `summarise_at()` or `summarise_if()` instead. To map `funs` over a
>   selection of variables, use `summarise_at()`

When i change the code for _all, at or _if, this function doest not work any more. I'm looking for some advice and thanks much for your support.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a string expression with `sprintf` and then evaluating it, we can use the evaluate the 'vs' converting it to symbol and then evaluate it

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
   summarise_at(vars(vars_to_test), funs( 
     try(stats::t.test(.[(!! rlang::sym(iv)) == 0], .[(!! rlang::sym(iv)) == 1])$p.value)
  ))
#          disp           hp       drat           wt         qsec
#1 2.476526e-06 1.819806e-06 0.01285342 0.0007281397 3.522404e-06
```

---

If we really wanted to parse an expression, use the `rlang_parse_expr` and `rlang::eval_tidy` along with `sym`

```
library(rlang)
eval_tidy(parse_expr("mtcars %>% summarise_at(vars(vars_to_test), 
                funs(t.test(.[(!!sym(iv))==0],
                                   .[(!!sym(iv))==1])$p.value ))"))
#          disp           hp       drat           wt         qsec
#1 2.476526e-06 1.819806e-06 0.01285342 0.0007281397 3.522404e-06
```

Comment: Thanks, @akrun. Could you please provide a code that i could replace this t.test to a t.test using ~ function ? This t.test is giving a result considering two continuous variables and my goal is a continuous dv in two groups (categorical)

Comment: @Luis It is not  clear from your comments.  Could you post as a new question.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, this code solved my question. I'll click there!  @akrun