# How to do numerous t.test withing my dataframe (multiple groups/outcomes, multiple quantitative variable)?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

By running **multiple t.test within R (multiple group compared according to multiple quantitative variable)**, I would like to get something like this within R:

[image: excel sheet]

I tried and modified the solution provided here:
[dplyr summarise multiple columns using t.test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26244321/dplyr-summarise-multiple-columns-using-t-test)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data(mtcars)


vars_to_test <- c("disp","hp","drat","wt","qsec")
iv <- c("vs", "am")


mtcars %>%
  summarise_each_(
    funs_( 
      sprintf("stats::t.test(.[%s == 0], .[%s == 1])$p.value",iv,iv)
    ), 
    vars = vars_to_test)
```

Here is the output:

```
     disp_$..1      hp_$..1  drat_$..1      wt_$..1    qsec_$..1    disp_$..2   hp_$..2    drat_$..2     wt_$..2 qsec_$..2
1 2.476526e-06 1.819806e-06 0.01285342 0.0007281397 3.522404e-06 0.0002300413 0.2209796 5.266742e-06 6.27202e-06 0.2093498
```

**I am facing multiple issues:**

- (1) I have two warnings messages that i don't how two solve

```
Please use summarise_if(), summarise_at(), or summarise_all() instead: 

  - To map `funs` over all variables, use summarise_all()
  - To map `funs` over a selection of variables, use summarise_at()
This warning is displayed once per session. 
2: funs_() is deprecated. 
Please use list() instead
```

- (2) How to get one row per group/outcome ?
- (3) How to change the "1" (first character of the second row) by the name of the group (ie : "vs" and "am" in this case)?
- (4) How to export this output as a dataframe (as in my begining example)

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply `summarise_at` for each varibale in `iv` using `map_dfr`

```
vars_to_test <- c("disp","hp","drat","wt","qsec")
iv <- c("vs", "am")
#map_dfr use these names as id
names(iv) <- iv

library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map_dfr(iv,  function(x) mtcars %>%
  summarise_at(vars_to_test,
    list( 
       #!! and parse_expr will transfer the string "output of sprintf" into epression
     ~!!(parse_expr(sprintf("stats::t.test(.[%s == 0], .[%s == 1])$p.value", x, x)))
    )), .id = "group")

  group         disp           hp         drat           wt         qsec
1    vs 2.476526e-06 1.819806e-06 1.285342e-02 7.281397e-04 3.522404e-06
2    am 2.300413e-04 2.209796e-01 5.266742e-06 6.272020e-06 2.093498e-01
```

Both `summarise_each_` and `funs_` are deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

```
library(tidyverse)

vars_to_test <- c("disp","hp","drat","wt","qsec")
iv <- c("vs", "am")

expand.grid(vars_to_test, iv, stringsAsFactors = F) %>%              # create pairs of variables
  rowwise() %>%                                                      # for each pair
  mutate(p_val = t.test(mtcars[,Var1] ~ mtcars[,Var2])$p.value) %>%  # get p value from t.test
  spread(Var1, p_val)                                                # reshape output

# # A tibble: 2 x 6
#   Var2        disp       drat         hp       qsec         wt
#   <chr>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1 am    0.000230   0.00000527 0.221      0.209      0.00000627
# 2 vs    0.00000248 0.0129     0.00000182 0.00000352 0.000728
```